# xpath (Python lxml): OR for element tag

Tags: xpath, lxml

I have the following xpath:

```
"//div[@id='instructions']//ol[@id='inst']"
```

However, what I have as the OL tag can be either OL or UL.

Not sure how to do that.

Comment: "//div[@id='instructions']//ol[@id='inst'] | //div[@id='instructions']//ul[@id='inst']"?

Comment: That did it :) I'll mark it as the right answer if you want to write it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following to match **both** ul an ol:

```
//div[@id='instructions']//ol[@id='inst'] | //div[@id='instructions']//ul[@id='inst']
```